# Choice of cost function in Michael Neilsen's book: Neural Networks and deep learning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

[image]

> Here, **w** denotes the collection of all weights in the network, **b** all
>   the biases, **n** is the total number of training inputs, **a** is the vector
>   of outputs from the network when **x** is input, and the sum is over all
>   training inputs, **x**. Of course, the output aa depends on **x**, **w** and **b**,
>   but to keep the notation simple I haven't explicitly indicated this
>   dependence.

Taken from Michael Neilsen's Neural Network and Deep Learning

Does anyone know why he divides the sum by 2? I thought he was going to find the average by dividing by **n**; instead, he divides by **2n**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done so that when the partial derivatives of *C(w, b)* are computed, it will counter out with the 2 that is produced by the derivative of the quadratic term.

You are correct, normally we'd divide by *n*, but this trick is done for computational ease.